# Can regression to the mean also impact heterogeneity?

Tags: r, regression, experiment-design

I understand [**Regression to the Mean**](https://conjointly.com/kb/regression-to-the-mean/) (**RM**) as a naturally (and likely randomly) occurring shift in the scores of a sample of extreme subjects (super high or low scorers) from each measurement time to another measurement time toward the center/location of a general population (i.e., one that consists of all ranges of low to high ability subjects).

When RM occurs, then it can confound the actual change in subjects' aggregate (mean) performance resulting from a treatment (i.e., errounousely taking the mean up or down).

If my understanding is correct, then I'm wondering whether, in addition to impacting the subjects' aggregate (mean) performance, RM can also impact the heterogeneity in subjects' performances (i.e., errounousely taking the heterogeneity up or down) at each measurement time relative to previous measurement times (see Figure below)?

P.S. I would also appreciate an `R` demonstration, if possible.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I do not like the page you linked to at all. It confuses things.

Regression to the mean occurs because two phenomena are not perfectly correlated. This can occur for various reasons.

One example of regression to the mean is that, if you look at sets of parents and kids and their heights, then the very tallest parents will not have the very tallest children. Yes, the children of tall parents will be taller than average, but the kids of the tallest parents may be the 3rd or 4th or whatever tallest kids. Similarly at the short end. Why? Because while height is partly genetic, it's not completely so.

Another is that the kids who score highest on the midterm may not score highest on the final. They will usually score higher than average, but the ranks and scores won't be identical. This is because, on nearly all tests given in schools, some of the grade is random, based on luck (e.g. guessing right on a multiple choice test) or other factors unrelated to ability (if you had a big fight with your romantic partner the night before the test, you may do worse).

If two phenomena were perfectly correlated, then this would not occur.

As to your question: RM cannot erroneously do anything, and it's not clear what "taking heterogeneity up or down" means.  RM is a consequence of heterogeneity, not a cause of it. If everyone's scores were perfectly homongenous, then there would be no RM. If boys grew up to be exactly the same heights as their fathers, then, again, no RM.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! That website does indicate that RM *"is a statistical phenomenon that occurs whenever you have a nonrandom sample from a population and two measures that are imperfectly correlated"*. As to my question, please look at the figure I added to my original post. These are the test results (ranging from 0 to 1) from a single group of subjects over 3 testing occasions. Because at the pre-test, subjects show fairly low performance, and the tests over the testing occasions are imperfectly correlated can we conclude that RM is at work? If yes, is RM able to confound the means at .  .  .

Comment: . . .  post-test1 and post-test 2? Books say potentially yes, especially in a design like this where pre-test results are fairly low, the post-tests' means are likely upwardly biased. 

But my question is that in addition to the upward bias in the posttests' means, are the post test scores likely more heterogenous due to the RM than pre-test scores?

Comment: What your diagram shows is generally rising scores from pre test to post 1 to post 2.  That is not RM.  If the tests are any kind of ability test, then a gradual rise is normal. If there was treatment between the times, then even more so.

Comment: This study was about the effect of practice (the treatment). So subjects, wrote on a topic on each testing occasion. Of course RM could be at play here as regards the means but that doesn't mean that all improvements over time are due to RM. Of course the best way to gauge whether RM is at work was to have a (valid) control group which could give me couterfactual comparison (what could my [treatment] subject do without writing practice), but sadly I don't. My question is if, in addition to the means, heterogeneity at each time might have been different.